# how can i add a span inside TextField after the input?

Tags: material-ui

using material-ui in react.js, i'm trying to target invalid TextField components with css. i can't use :input:before or :input:after so i'd like to inject a span after the input, so it can be styled with `:invalid+span`. is there a way pass in a span without rewriting the entire component?

`<TextField
    required={true}
    InputProps={{}}
/>`

i suppose i could use InputAdornment but the TextField textarea doesn't place InputAdornment in the same spot. Anyone know how to inject the span after the input element?